# How to add File image in qr_flutter to generate QR code with that embedded image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to do similar think like this ( [How to generate QR CODE with logo in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829863/how-to-generate-qr-code-with-logo-in-flutter/58830139#58830139) ) but instead of using asset image, I want to user pick an image with image_picker package and then store that image in file and use it in QR code as an embedded image. Please anyone help me out.

Thank You

Comment: Hi! Please provide code you tried out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well The Thing you want to achieve has some boilerplate code involved so I would break it down into 2 brief steps:

**Step 1:** Pick Image as a File using image picker plugin that is, simply store image as File you can achieve it using:

```
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50
  );
```

You can follow [this to perfectly get image](https://medium.com/fabcoding/adding-an-image-picker-in-a-flutter-app-pick-images-using-camera-and-gallery-photos-7f016365d856)

**Step 2:** Now if you see the type of embedded image is actually an **ImageProvider** so you can use **FileImage()** and do:

```
QrImage(
              data: 'This QR code has an embedded image as well',
              version: QrVersions.auto,
              size: 320,
              gapless: false,
              //You can use image here, Note this image should be of type File 
              embeddedImage: FileImage(image),
              embeddedImageStyle: QrEmbeddedImageStyle(
                size: Size(80, 80),
              ),
            ),
```

Hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: `The argument type 'FileImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image?'.` Still having the issue.

Comment: Plugin must be changed you can try using Image.file(image) to it @SiddharthMehra

Comment: I have tried this also. `The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image?'.`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a variable of the image that you will use for QR :

```
var image = Image.asset('assets/ur_image.png',);
```

and then add it in here :

```
QrImage(
   embeddedImage: image.image,
   data: 'hello',
    version: QrVersions.auto,
    size: 100,
  ),
```